# To check if var is String type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a problem in code in C#:

I don't know how to implement logic - iterating through Hashtable
having values of different data types, the schema I want is below:

```
if the value in variable is String type
{
 do action1;
}
else 
{
  do action2;
}
```

---

There is a hashtable containing data of Types - String and Int (combined):

```
public string SQLCondGenerator {

        get
        {

            Hashtable conditions = new Hashtable();

            //data having String data type
            conditions.Add("miap", ViewState["miap_txt"]);
            conditions.Add("pocode", ViewState["po_txt "]);
            conditions.Add("materialdescription", ViewState["mat_desc_txt"]);
            conditions.Add("suppliername", ViewState["supplier_txt"]);
            conditions.Add("manufacturername", ViewState["manufacturer_txt"]);

            //data having Int32 data type
            conditions.Add("spareparts", ViewState["sp_id"]); 
            conditions.Add("firstfills", ViewState["ff_id"]);
            conditions.Add("specialtools", ViewState["st_id"]);
            conditions.Add("ps_deleted", ViewState["ps_del_id"]);
            conditions.Add("po_manuallyinserted", ViewState["man_ins_id"]);

            String SQLCondString = "";
            String SQLCondStringConverted = "";


            string s = string.Empty;
            foreach (string name in conditions.Keys) 
            {
                if (conditions[name] != null)
                {
                    SQLCondString += name+ "=" +conditions[name]+ " and ";
                    Response.Write(conditions[name].GetType());

                    bool valtype = conditions[name].GetType().IsValueType;
                    if (valtype == string)
                    {
                      SQLCondString.Substring(0, SQLCondString.Length - 4);
                      SQLCondString += name + " and like '%" + conditions[name] + "%' and ";
                    }
                }
            }

        //Response.Write("********************");
         SQLCondStringConverted = SQLCondString.Substring(0, SQLCondString.Length - 4);
         return SQLCondStringConverted;
        }   
    }
```

May be I am wrong in coding, please advise!

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Don't use `HashTable`, use `Dictionary` as it's generic.  2) Don't have some values be strings and others ints, if you need to treat them differently.  Have two dictionaries, one for ints and one for strings.

Comment: How does this have 2 upvotes... if you copy and paste his title directly into google you get a ton of answers....

Comment: Why the precious attitude to upvotes?  They are free and abundantly available.  Thankfully, there are as many upvotes as downvotes.  And until Google and Bing start using SO's votes in their search algorithms (God forbid!), I don't see that it matters within reason.  Personally, if there is a question generating alternative answers, I pay much more attention to the comments than the votes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
if(conditions[name] is string)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Hmm, I'm not sure why you are calling `IsValueType`, but this should be sufficient:

```
if (conditions[name] is string) 
{
    ///  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Approach - 1

```
Int32 Val = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse("Your Value", out Val))
{
    //Your Logic for int
}
else
{
    //Your Logic for String
}
```

### Approach - 2  (using Late Binding)

```
Int32 Val = 0;
dynamic conditions = new Hashtable();
conditions.Add("miap", ViewState["miap_txt"]);
conditions.Add("pocode", ViewState["po_txt "]);
foreach (string name in conditions.Keys)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(conditions[name].ToString(), out Val))
    {
        //Your Logic for int
    }
    else
    {
        //Your Logic for String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I was using textBoxes and needed to validate if the input is alphabets,-, or .

I generated a keypress event on my textBox and inserted the following method to check each keypress and give a prompt if its not a valid character:

```
public static class Validator
{
public static bool IsNameString(TextBox tb, string name, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        bool valid = true;

        /*  e.KeyChar contains the character that was pressed
         e.Handled is a boolean that indicates that handling is done            
        if a bad character is entered, set e.Handled to true
        */
        if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ' ' && e.KeyChar != '-' &&
          e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            valid = false;
            MessageBox.Show(name+ " can only accept letters, space, - and .");
            tb.Focus();

        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

---

usage:

```
 private void txtCustomerName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
       Validator.IsNameString(txtCustomerName, "Customer Name", e);

    }
```